# Hide a class in a .jar

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, hide

Whenever I build my app all classes (logically) are visible in the .jar that comes out of it.
Aswell as a class that holds information to my MYSQL server (for the app to connect to). But I dont want this information to be publicly visible!

How can I "hide" this code or "hide" the class?

Thanks!!

Comment: That probably means that the app shouldn't talk to the database directly.

Comment: The short answer is that you can't.  No matter what you do, someone else can find your data.  Regardless of how you might choose to encrypt it, someone can find the code you're using to decrypt and therefore can decrypt it themselves.  A class obfuscator will help somewhat, but it won't be truly secure;  a determined person will still be able to extract the information in less than a day.  The only secure solution is not to embed the login information in the application, and instead to make the user enter that information.

Comment: That means my users will need to know the pw to the database, the schema et cetera. I dont think thats the idea :P

Comment: Anyone else got a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean you dont want someone to do reverse engineering with your .class inside your jar file. There are many decompilers that can do that.
So you would need to Obfuscate your code with an obfuscator utility.

The process of obfuscation will convert bytecode into a  logical
equivalent version that is extremely difficult for decompilers to pick
apart. Keep in mind that the decompilation process is extremely
complicated and cannot be easily 'tweaked' to bypassed obfuscated
code. Essentially the process is as follows:

1. Compile Java source code using a regular compiler (ie. JDK)
2. Run the obfuscator, passing in the compiled class file as a
   parameter. The result will be a different output file (perhaps with a
   different extension).

This file, when renamed as a .class file, will be functionally
equivalent to the original bytecode. It will not affect performance
because a virtual machine will still be able to interpret it.

Here is an article describing this process in more detail and
introducing an early obfuscator, Crema:

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip22.html

Comment: Ive used proguard for obfuscation. Yet, the class (ConnectionClass)is still visible because I put values to strings.